# How to work with data in a dictionary in a .txt archive?

Tags: python

I am creating a registration system, which register the username and password of a person in a dictionary and then passes that dictionary to a .txt file. See the example:

```
user = 'Lucas'
password = '1234'

dic = {}
dic[user] = password

import pickle
archive = open('data.txt', 'ab')
pickle.dump(dic, archive)
archive.close()

archive = open('data.txt', 'rb')
dic = pickle.load(archive)
archive.close()
print(dic)
```

The problem is that my program will register infinite users and forever, so if now I put another user and another password it should return a dictionary with **all users already registered + the user being registered**, the problem is that it is returning a dictionary **only** with the last registered user. How could I solve it?

Comment: You need to read the data into `dic` before you write. Just to clarify btw, if this is to be used by others, you shouldn't be storing the unhashed password.

Comment: It's going to be used just by me. I'm a beginner and I'm doing some projects, it's simple stuff. But I still don't know what to do

Comment: Put the load before everything else, and remove `dic = {}`. You want `dic` to be populated with every value when you dump it back to the file.